# How to select items based on property with Read-Archive in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to extract a `.txt` file from an archive using the `Expand-Archive` cmdlet from [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://pscx.codeplex.com/).

It seems that filtering through the objects I get from `Read-Archive` isn't working, and that if one object matches, it returns all objects.

For example, when I run the command:

```
Read-Archive D:\Temp\test.zip  | ? {$_.Name -like "*.txt"}
```

I expect to only recieve the `.txt` files in the archive. Instead, I recieve all the files:

```
Index      Size Name                                    
-----      ---- ----                                    
0          6137 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831.txt    
1         40965 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_001.tif
2         72280 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_002.tif
3         51954 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_003.tif
4        104179 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_004.tif
5        104418 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_005.tif
6         39255 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_006.tif
7         39203 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_007.tif
8         63999 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_008.tif
9        729953 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_009.tif
10        46779 0723_20150413_20150413_000121831_010.tif
```

Am I misunderstanding this cmdlet? Or am I using it incorrectly?

**Note:** This is using PowerShell 4.0, not 5.0. So the technet article on the 5.0 cmdlet is not relevant here.

Comment: see this [discuss](https://pscx.codeplex.com/discussions/452376)

Answer (score 0):

Well using the in-built Get-ChildItem cmdlet does yield the desired result:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Documents\' -Filter "*.txt"
```

Does Read-Archive include a -Filter switch?
You could also try:

```
Read-Archive D:\Temp\test.zip  | %{Write-Host $_} #Write out the individual line
```

Comment: It does not include a filter switch. And If you do `%{Write-Host $_}` it would just write each line. I'm more trying to figure out why the `Where-Object` function isn't working with `Read-Archive`.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at Soheil's comment, I was able to figure out a way to get it to work.

If you do:

```
Read-Archive D:\Temp\test.zip  | ? {$_.Name -like "*.txt"}
```

It will give all of the items back to you.

But if you put it in parentheses like this:

```
(Read-Archive D:\Temp\test.zip)  | ? {$_.Name -like "*.txt"}
```

It functions as expected. This seems to be a known issue with this cmdlet.